# Import Comma Delimited to Specific WorkSheet

Tags: excel, vba, import

I am trying to import a comma delimited text file into a specific sheet in my workbook. The code I have imports it, but I cant figure out how to tell it to go to a specific sheets thats already created, as right now it just creates a new sheet and dumps the data in there.

The code I have is

```
'Import Report

      Dim vPath As Variant
      Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
      Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

      Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
      Set ws = Excel.Sheets("Data")
      vPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV (Comma Delimited) (*.csv),*.csv" _
      , 1, "Select a file", , False)

      ''//Show the file open dialog to allow user to select a CSV file

      If vPath = False Then Exit Sub

      ''//Exit macro if no file selected

      Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=vPath, Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1 _
      , DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True _
      , FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlTextFormat), Array(2, xlTextFormat), _
      Array(3, xlTextFormat))

      ''//The fieldinfo array needs to be extended to match your number of columns

      Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit

      ''//Resize the columns

      Sheets(1).Move Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

      ''//Move the data into the Workbook
```

I think I just need to add something like;

```
Destination:=Range("Sheet2!$A$1")
```

somewhere, but I cant figure out where, everywhere Ive tried has caused errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
Sub CSV_Reader()
      Dim vPath As Variant
      Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
      Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
      Dim rng As Range, TextLine As String
      Dim rw As Long, col As Long
      Dim i As Long, j As Long, ary() As String, a As Variant

      Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook

      vPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV (Comma Delimited) (*.csv),*.csv" _
         , 1, "Select a file", , False)
      MsgBox vPath
      Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick a Sheet and a Cell", Type:=8)
      rng.Parent.Parent.Activate
      rng.Parent.Activate
      rw = rng(1).Row
      col = rng(1).Column

      Close #1
      i = rw
      Open vPath For Input As #1
      Do While Not EOF(1)
         Line Input #1, TextLine
         ary = Split(TextLine, ",")
         j = col
         For Each a In ary
            Cells(i, j).Value = a
            j = j + 1
         Next a
         i = i + 1
      Loop
      Close 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way I found works, (just in case anyone else ever has this question, they can find it) without the user interaction (so they cant mess it up)

```
Sub Import()
Dim rFirstCell As Range 'Points to the First Cell in the row currently being     updated
Dim rCurrentCell As Range 'Points the the current cell in the row being updated
Dim sCSV As String 'File Name to Import
Dim iFileNo As Integer 'File Number for Text File operations
Dim sLine As String 'Variable to read a line of file into
Dim sValue As String 'Individual comma delimited value

'Prompt User for File to Import
sCSV = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files, *.CSV", , "Select File to Import")
If sCSV = "False" Then Exit Sub

'Clear Existing Data
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells.Delete
'wsData.Cells.Delete 'Use this method if you set the vb-name of the sheet

'Set initial values for Range Pointers
Set rFirstCell = Sheets("Data").Range("A1")
Set rCurrentCell = rFirstCell

'Get an available file number
iFileNo = FreeFile

'Open your CSV file as a text file
Open sCSV For Input As #iFileNo

'Loop until reaching the end of the text file
Do Until EOF(iFileNo)

    'Read in a line of text from the CSV file
    Line Input #iFileNo, sLine

    Do
        sValue = ParseData(sLine, ",")

        If sValue <> "" Then
            rCurrentCell = sValue 'put value into cell
            Set rCurrentCell = rCurrentCell.Offset(0, 1) 'move current cell one column right
        End If

    Loop Until sValue = ""

    Set rFirstCell = rFirstCell.Offset(1, 0) 'move pointer down one row
    Set rCurrentCell = rFirstCell 'set output pointer to next line
Loop

'Close the Text File
Close #iFileNo

End Sub

Private Function ParseData(sData As String, sDelim As String) As String
Dim iBreak As Integer

iBreak = InStr(1, sData, sDelim, vbTextCompare)

If iBreak = 0 Then
    If sData = "" Then
        ParseData = ""
    Else
        ParseData = sData
        sData = ""
    End If
Else
    ParseData = Left(sData, iBreak - 1)
    sData = Mid(sData, iBreak + 1)
End If

End Function
```